Any way to bring YouTube comments that are other than in English
I am currently developing a code that brings a number of comments from songs in playlist through Google YouTube API. However, the code doesn't seem to work with a video which has comments written in language other than English:
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey='My_API Key')


def fetch_comments(video_id):
    try:
        request=youtube.commentThreads().list(
            part="snippet,replies",
            videoId=video_id,
            maxResults=10,
            order = "relevance"
        ).execute()

        for item in request['items']:
            comment = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textOriginal']

    except HttpError as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e.resp.status} {e.resp.reason}")

def get_playlist_items(youtube, playlist_id, max_results=15):
    # List to hold all the video URLs
    video_urls = []

    # Make the API call to fetch playlist items
    request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
        part='snippet',
        playlistId=playlist_id,
        maxResults=max_results
    )
    response = request.execute()

    # Extract video IDs from the response and generate URLs
    for item in response.get('items', []):
        video_id = item['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']
        video_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}"
        video_urls.append(video_url)

    return video_urls


f = open("playlist.txt", 'r')

lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    URL = line.split(', ')[0]
    number = int(line.split(', ')[1])
    playlist_id = URL.split('=')[-1]
    video_urls = get_playlist_items(youtube, playlist_id)
    print(len(video_urls))
    for url in video_urls :
        print(url)
        video_id = url.split('=')[-1]
        fetch_comments(video_id)

f.close()

An example of error message looks like this:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The video identified by the \u003ccode\u003e\u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#videoId\"\u003evideoId\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/code\u003e parameter has disabled comments.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The video identified by the \u003ccode\u003e\u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#videoId\"\u003evideoId\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/code\u003e parameter has disabled comments.",
        "domain": "youtube.commentThread",
        "reason": "commentsDisabled",
        "location": "videoId",
        "locationType": "parameter"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Initially, this error message was intended for the case where the video actually has disabled comments or threads so that there is nothing to display for the code:
except HttpError as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e.resp.status} {e.resp.reason}")

However, the error message still displays for videos that haven't disabled the comments if they have comments written in language other than English.
Secondly, as I printed the number of songs that I retrieved from the playlist, each trial had a small discrepancy from the max_result variable. I was expecting 15 songs to be retrieved, but in some cases, the program stops at 14 or even less. (And not because the playlist had less song numbers than the max_result value.)
I've tried to encompass characters in unicode, but it didn't work:
print(comment.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')) 

I have also tried to translate the comment before processing it:
translated_comment = translator.translate(comment, dest=target_language).text
print(translated_comment)

However, this didn't turn out well as well, and I have completely no idea about the second issue.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question seems to include two different questions - please [edit] this one to only include one, and potentially ask the second in a separate post.

Provide a video id having the issue.
